# Как выводить самые новый записи, не затрагивая старые MySql

Tags: mysql, ajax

Не понимаю логику, вот как взять именно новые записи, не трогая старые.
Т.е добавились у меня новые записи, и через ajax запрос беру именно их но не трогаю старые.

Я хочу сделать плавное добавление нового элемента если он есть.
Сейчас я только знаю как загрузить все разом и новые и старые.

Можно проверить уже старые выведенные элементы html.
Т.е пришли новые записи, если в списке есть новая запись, как-то  добавить её, как то проверить. Получается дубли просто не добавлять а новые добавлять.
Или есть ли способы как то понимать что новые записи новые, еще не выведенные?
Подскажите куда копать мне, я не могу додуматься а решение может быть где то рядом!

Answer (score 0):

В SQL есть LIMIT - ограничение по кол-ву.
Также есть DESC - обратная сортировка.
Пример:
SQL запрос `SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY` ID `DESC LIMIT 10` - вывести 10 последних статей, с обратной сортировкой по колонке ID